# Какого падежа требует глагол "быть" с отрицанием?

Tags: падежи

Вчера МНЕ не было на лекции или МЕНЯ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не было (кого?) - меня. Родительный падеж. Мне - дательный падеж.

Answer (score 0):

Меня не было (=Не было меня).
Это безличная форма для "Я не был (на лекции)".

Глаголы с отрицанием обычно требуют родительного падежа (в некоторых случаях - винительного).

Не было меня, друга, папы, тетради, еды, терпения, детей, яблок.